# Auto-convert snake case to camel case in Grails REST API?

Tags: mongodb, rest, grails

In a Grails REST API project, by default Grails reads properties and renders properties assuming camel case ([camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)). However, in many prevalent REST APIs the name of parameters are standardized on snake case ([snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)). How can I most effectively enable this automatic conversion in Grails?

For example, in a request body I'd like to accept snake case input.

```
{
  "first_name": "John"
}
```

And in the response body I'd like to send snake case output.

```
{
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

But I want to keep my domain class streamlined following Groovy conventions in Grails, using camel case and Groovy's auto-generated getters and setters.

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

And I'd like to avoid changing my MongoDB schema, where 99% of fields are named with camelCase. However I do see that at least [in the MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/), the preference is to name MongoDB fields with snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/google/gson to serialize/deserialize your classes, and set a field naming policy:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .create()`

This implies that you should get your request/response bodies as text, and not rely on the automagic json deserialization that Grails provides.

Another option, at least for your responses, is to register a custom JSON marshaller. You can do this in bootstrap.groovy. In my sample code below I have implemented a marker interface so that objects that should be serialized as snake case can be explicitly nominated.

```
interface SnakeCase {
}
```

Domain objects you want to export as snake case implement this interface

```
class Person implements SnakeCase {

    String surname
    String firstName
    String middleNames
    String someOtherField

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Then in bootstrap.groovy a custom JSON marshaller is registered

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(SnakeCase, { SnakeCase o ->

            def result = [:]
            if (grailsApplication.isDomainClass(o.class)) {
                o.domainClass.persistentProperties.each { GrailsDomainClassProperty p ->
                   def name = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, p.name)
                    result[name] = o[p.name]
                }
            } else {
                o.properties.each {
                    def name = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, it.key as String)
                result[name] = it.value
                }
            }

            return result

        })
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Note that a distinction is made between grails domain classes or regular POGO classes. You could also add black/white list mechanism to have finer control over which properties get serialized. This example uses the Guava CaseFormat utilities to perform the actual snake casing

Once this marshaller has been registered, it's just a matter of using the JSON formatter in your controller methods

```
def ajaxListPeople() {

    def list = Person.list();

    render(list as JSON)
}
```